# Ionic 3 Cordova File plugin gives error for copyFile operation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to copy a file from one dir to another using the `copyFile(path, fileName, newPath, newFileName)` function. It gives an error like `{"code":13, "message":"input is not a directory"}`. The documentation has only 12 error code and no 13th. I'd like to know what i did wrong please.

Here is a sample of my actual code.

```
this.path = "file:///storage/emulated/0/TheFolder/thefile.ext";
this.newPath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/NewFolder";

this.fileCtrl.copyFile(this.path, fileName, this.newPath, newFileName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this.path must be a directory but your are showing some  file name

change your code as follows

```
this.path = "file:///storage/emulated/0/TheFolder";
this.newPath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/NewFolder";

this.fileCtrl.copyFile(this.path, YOUR_EXISTING_FILE_NAME, this.newPath, NEW_FILE_NAME);


path -Base FileSystem
fileName - Name of file to copy
newPath - Base FileSystem of new location
newFileName - New name of file to copy to (leave blank to remain the same)
```